# rails migrating from paperclip to carrierwave_direct

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip, carrierwave

I have migrated from Paperclip to Carrierwave, and using Carrierwave_direct to upload images directly to S3.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :profile_picture, ProfilePictureUploader, :mount_on => :profile_picture_file_name
```

So, in my schema, I don't have column `profile_picture` but `profile_picture_file_name` in my users table.

This creates problem when I am trying to create the `@uploader` instance variable

```
class ProfilePictureController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user=current_user
    @uploader = @user.profile_picture_file_name
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = crop_url
  end
```

This throws an error, when a user is trying to upload the Profile Image,
`` undefined method `success_action_redirect=' for nil:NilClass ``

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could fix it:

`@uploader = @user.profile_picture`